# Soyuz flight books?

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft

I have the Crew Operations Manual, but I wonder if any of the books carried onboard mentioned in it are available anywhere? There is a flight plan book, a nominal checklist, off-nominal, backup and reference book mentioned.

Comment: Following! Would love to have some.

Comment: You don't happen to have an L2 account for Nasaspaceflight to ask there?

Comment: No. Not a fan of that site.

Answer (score 3):

Of course there are such books in the Russian State Archive of Scientific-Technical Documentation.

[For example](https://rgantd.kaisa.ru/search?search?type=custom&searchObjectType=4220&p0.t=%D0%A4.%201%20%D0%9E%D0%BF.%208-1&p0.d=185671959&p0.v=185671959&p0.a=4890&p0.c=10&page4220=1)

- Бортовой журнал космического корабля № 3, т. I.
- Бортовой журнал космического корабля № 3, т. II.
- Инструкция экипажу космического корабля 3КВ по действиям после приземления в безлюдной местности.
- Общая полетная инструкция пилота при номинальном полете на один виток (для объекта "Восток-3А").  -
- Инструкция по эксплуатации скафандра СК-1, системы кислородного питания и вентиляции и системы АСУ при полете в объекте "Восток-3А".
- Инструкция по работе с приборной доской (ПД-1-3   КА), пультом управления (ПУ-13 КА) и рукояткой управления (РУ-1-3 КА) при номинальном полете на один виток.
- Инструкция летчику по  определению координат местоположения астрономическими методами после  приземления.
- Краткое описание работы пилота при ручном управлении спуском объекта "Восток-3А" с орбиты.
- Журнал космонавта-исследователя космического корабля "Союз-1".
- Бортовой журнал космического корабля "Союз-2".
- Журнал бортинженера космического корабля "Союз-2".
- Журнал космонавта-исследователя корабля "Союз-2".
- Spaceship Logbook No. 3, vol. I.
- Spaceship Logbook No. 3, vol. II.
- Instructions to the crew of the 3KV spacecraft on actions after  landing in a deserted area.
- The general flight instruction of the pilot during the nominal flight for one turn (for the object "Vostok-3A").
- Operating instructions for the SK-1 space suit, the oxygen supply and  ventilation system, and the automated control system during flight in   the Vostok-3A .
- Instructions for working with the instrument panel (PD-1-3 KA),  control panel (PU-13 KA) and control stick (RU-1-3 KA) during a nominal one-turn flight.
- Instructions to the pilot on determining the coordinates of the   location by astronomical methods after landing.
- A brief description of the pilot's work during manual control of the  descent of the Vostok-3A object from orbit.
- Logbook of the cosmonaut-researcher of the Soyuz-1 spacecraft.
- On-board Logbook of the Soyuz-2 spacecraft.
- Logbook of the flight engineer of the Soyuz-2 spacecraft.
- Logbook of the cosmonaut-researcher of the Soyuz-2 spacecraft.

Comment: Is it possible for non-russians to access these?

Comment: @Innovine "Information to foreign citizens.

Be advised that foreign citizens should inform about the intended date of visiting the archive reading room no later than 10 (ten) working days ahead of time.

Foreign citizens should provide the following information: The last name, the first name, and patronymic (if any), citizenship and the passport data details, the purpose and topic of research, submit the basis for admittance (an official company letter or a written personal statement), the dates of intended visit, information on affiliation specifying position and contact information."